# Glassfish doesn't bring up EntityManager if DAO is not Stateless

Tags: jpa, glassfish, java-ee-6, cdi, ejb-3.1

I have an EAR application with an EJB module, that contains one persistence unit and many EJBs (as service and DAO layer).

```
@Stateless
public class BranchDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

But DAOs as Stateless beans are not recommended. So I create this annotation using CDI:

```
@Dependent
@Stereotype
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DAO {
}
```

After my DAO is changed to not use `@Stateless`:

```
@DAO
public class BranchDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
}
```

But the Glassfish doesn't bring up the entity manager when the application starts. And when I call the DAO, the entity manager is in an illegal state.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null

This error only occurs in Glassfish 3, but not in JBoss AS 6. Using JBoss AS 6 I can see the Hibernate logs in startup (but I don't see them with Glassfish).

As a temporary solution I created an Stateless bean with the content below. It's not beautiful solution, but works fine in Glassfish.

```
@Stateless
@Startup
public class AutoStartEntityManager {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

}
```

So, how I can force Glassfish to bring up EntityManager when I'm not using `@Stateless` in my DAO?

Comment: What's wrong with stateless DAOs?

Comment: See the Pascal answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223112/javaee6-dao-should-it-be-stateless-or-applicationscoped/3224607#3224607

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying explicitly the unitName:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="yourJPAUnitName")
private EntityManager manager;
```

(A sidenote - are you sure you need the DAO in dependent scope? Shouldn't it be singleton?)

Comment: I've tried this way (with unitName), but without success (same problem occurs). I'm using DAO as dependent to inherit scope from caller. I'm right? Regards.

Comment: yes, but that will mean you will have as many DAO instances as callers. And this is not needed.