# EJB Transactions

Tags: java, transactions, annotations, ejb

I am developing a Web Service using a Stateless EJB, which has a single entry point (method). This method has 3 steps and I want step 1 to occur in a different transaction than steps 2 and 3 (which should be in the same transaction). These "steps" consist in callings to injected Stateless EJBs. Let me explain with some code:

```java
@Stateless  
@WebService(...)  
public class MyWebServiceImpl implements MyWebService { 

     @EJB  
     private UserBusinessBean userBusinessBean;  

     @EJB  
     private EventsBusinessBean eventsBusinessBean;  

     @WebMethod(...)  
     public MyWebServiceResult process(MyWebServiceParam param) {  
          // extract data from param  
          EventResult createEventResult = eventsBusinessBean.createEvent(data); // step 1  
          // do some extra processing  
          User user = userBusinessBean.createUser(someData); // step 2  
          // do some extra processing  
          EventResult updateEventResult = eventsBusinessBean.updateEvent(moreData); // step 3  
     }  
}
```

The 2 injected EJBs are themselves Stateless and have injected references to Stateless DAOs, whose function is to call stored procedures on the database.

I need to have step 1 executing in one transaction and steps 2 and 3 executing in another transaction (because if step 2 or 3 fails, the info from step 1 is already committed).

I know I have 2 options to implement this: container-manager transactions or user-managed transactions. I believe the former approach is more safe than the latter, delegating the management to the container (in my case, a Weblogic server). But I can't understand how I should use the EJB Transactions Annotations to implement this logic. Should I annotate the methods from my injected Business Beans? And what about the DAOs, do they need to have annotations too? And which ones should I use?

I hope you can give me some help in this one. Let me know if you need to know more details from my implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `MyWebServiceImpl` is an `@Stateless`, it will implicitly have a `REQUIRED` transaction attribute.  To ensure step 1 is completed in its own transaction, you should add `@TransactionAttribute(REQUIRES_NEW)` to the `EventsBusinessBean.createBean` method.  That will cause the bean to be created in its own transaction, and then the remaining actions in `process` will operate within another transaction.

Comment: That solved the problem. I forgot that implicit `REQUIRED` attribute of my Web Service bean. I had to do some extra work throwing `ApplicationException`s to rollback the transactions. Thanks!

Comment: For DAOs check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223112/javaee6-dao-should-it-be-stateless-or-applicationscoped (in a few words DAOs should not be EJBs).