# Can't Inject DAO into EJB using CDI

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, ejb, cdi

I'm working on an application using EJB3, JPA and JSF and I'd like to inject my DAO into the EJB using CDI :

Here's my DAO's code :

```
    public class ZoneDao {

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "wabApp3PU")
        private EntityManager em;

        /* Functions */

    }
```

and here's my EJB code :

```
    @Stateless
    public class ZoneFacade{

        @Inject
        private ZoneDao zoneDao;

        /* Functions*/

    }
```

Here's the error I get :

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408 Unsatisfied dependencies for type [ZoneDao] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private fr.si.metier.ZoneFacade.zoneDao]
```

NB: I'm using the glassfish 4 application server

Comment: please add some details - like what container you're deploying to.

Comment: Check if you have `beans.xml` in the `META-INF` folder if you are using Java EE 6.

Answer (score 1):

JAVA EE 6 - CDI Component, give DAO @ApplicationScoped, then it'll allows inject the persistentcontext

Answer (score 0):

Add `@Stateless` to your `ZoneDao` Class or give this Bean a Scope e.g. `@SessionScoped`.

Make sure you have a beans.xml if using Java EE 6. With version 7 it is not required anymore.

Comment: I've already tried @stateless in my DAO bean and this works fine but is this a good solution ? and can't I inject a simple java Pojo into an EJB using CDI ?

Comment: You have to annotate a Pojo in some way to make it inject able. Plan Pojo-Injection should work with CDI, but seems to not be supported by JBoss. 

Using a Stateless Session Bean as DAO is very common - but there is another discussion about it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223112/javaee6-dao-should-it-be-stateless-or-applicationscoped)

Answer (score 0):

ZoneDao is not marked as a managed bean and so it won't work like that using CDI. Annotate ZoneDao with @Named , and choose it's scope using @RequestScope, @SessionScop,...etc or what ever scope you need, Only then it will be a managed bean that can be injected using CDI.

Answer (score 0):

1. Which IDE are you using? If Netbeans, check if it has generated beans.xml in the META-INF/WEB-INF folder. If it has, check to ensure that default bean-discovery mode is not set to annotated, if it is, annotate the DAO with @Dependent.
2. You cannot inject entitymanager into a CDI bean using @PersistenceContext.(Until the CDI guys, or the server vendors change this). Simple solution, as it seems you are learning is to inject the entitymanager in a stateless bean (and if you are using ejb in a war application, you can then inject the stateless EJB)